# On-the-fly downsampling with prometheus

Tags: python, prometheus

Every second we want to collect a range of metrics from a bunch of servers and store them in prometheus. We'll keep these high resolution metrics for say, 24 hours before discarding. We're looking for a way to downsample the metrics to 5 second and 1 minute averages so we can store these for much longer. We're wondering how do go about implementing this. Currently, we're looking at two possibilities.

1. We're planning on using the prometheus_client python library to collect and export the metrics. Perhaps we could implement 1, 5 & 60 second averages as a moving window function but then it seems we'd have to work out how to implement fixed length fifo stacks. This seems somehow possible with collections.deque.
2. We have some endpoint that reads the last 5 or 60 seconds of data from the one second data in prometheus and averages it. This then be called by different scrape which runs every 5 or 60 seconds.

Both of these options do the downsampling on the fly. Does anyone have alternative proposals or have any practical advice on how to move forward with either of these options?

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: Andrew, marc_s has fixed typos in your question. Why are you not happy?

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1. Run 2 Proms scraping the same targets but with different scrape_interval. Prom1 will get metrics scraped each 5s, Prom2 - each 60s. Prom1 will have retention 24h, Prom2 - whatever you'd like to. Then you choose which one to use for what. For example, Prom1 for alerting, Prom2 for dashboards.

Approach 2. Use [stream aggregation](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/stream-aggregation.html) feature from VictoriaMetrics. [vmagent](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html), metrics collector similar to prom or grafana agent, can collect metrics in the same way as Prometheus does, and forward the via Prometheus remote-write protocol to whatever compatible system.

Comment: With Approach one, we wouldn't be able to use the same target, we'd have to impliment a moving window function in the client for the 60s interval to make the average.